# Generate multi-column Pivot Table (Like Excel) in LinQ/Lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of Employee Objects which has data like this.

[image]

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Department {get; set;}
    public string Skill {get; set;}
    public string Gender {get; set;}
    public string Experience {get; set;}
}
```

Now I want to generate a Pivot table like I can do in MS Excel like this.

[image]

The requirement is:

1. The Pivot table rows will group by Department and Skill
2. the columns will show the count of Employees
3. Each column will be split into 2 genders

I have created a class to store the Output Rows.

```
public class Pivot
{        
    public string Department {get; set;}
    public string Skill {get; set;}

    public int Male_0_to_5 {get; set;}
    public int Female_0_to_5 {get; set;}

    public int Male_5_to_10 {get; set;}
    public int Female_5_to_10 {get; set;}

    public int Male_10_to_15 {get; set;}
    public int Female_10_to_15 {get; set;}
}
```

My Goal is to populate a List of `Pivot` objects.

Is there any easy way to achieve this in LINQ? 
I can use several nested foreach loops to populate the table manually, but looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the employees by department and skill by using anonymous objects, then create a `Pivot` instance with the matching counts of every group entry:

```
var pivot = employees
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Department, x.Skill })
    .Select(x => new Pivot
    {
        Department = x.First().Department,
        Skill = x.First().Skill,
        Female_0_to_5 = x.Count(e => e.Gender == "Female" && e.Experience == "0-5 Years"),
        Male_0_to_5 = x.Count(e => e.Gender == "Male" && e.Experience == "0-5 Years"),
        Female_5_to_10 = x.Count(e => e.Gender == "Female" && e.Experience == "5-10 Years"),
        Male_5_to_10 = x.Count(e => e.Gender == "Male" && e.Experience == "5-10 Years"),
        Female_10_to_15 = x.Count(e => e.Gender == "Female" && e.Experience == "10-15 Years"),
        Male_10_to_15 = x.Count(e => e.Gender == "Male" && e.Experience == "10-15 Years"),
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Department)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Skill)
    .ToList();
```